# Why adding forward slash in front and back of pattern in preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Does anyone know why are we adding forward slash in front and back of pattern in *preg_match* method in PHP?

```
preg_match('/test/', "Welcome to testing world");
```

Also how to add them dynamically to pattern?

Comment: Simple: `$pattern = "test"; preg_match("/$pattern/", "Welcome to testing world");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delimiter is a special character used at the start and end of your expression to denote which part is the expression. This allows you to use modifiers and the interpreter to know which is an expression and which are modifiers.

Example:

```
preg_match('/Test/', "Welcome to testing world"); //nothing found
preg_match('/Test/i', "Welcome to testing world"); //i -> case-insensitive search, all ok
```